# Start x-axis ticks from origin

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

There are multiple plots stacked over one another. The ticks on x axis for each plot starts from 184.0
Are there any possible way to start my x ticks from origin with value 184.0 itself?

The plot I have is:
[image]

```
#create a figure and edit size
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(20,17))

#define subplots and define their position
plt1=fig.add_subplot(611)
plt2=fig.add_subplot(612)
plt3=fig.add_subplot(613)
plt4=fig.add_subplot(614)
plt5=fig.add_subplot(615)
plt6=fig.add_subplot(616)


plt1.plot("DOY", "By", data=df,color='black')
plt1.set_ylabel("By",size=16)
plt1.set_title("3-6 July 2003",size=20)
plt1.get_yaxis().set_label_coords(-0.05,0.5)

plt2.plot("DOY", "Bz", data=df,color='black')
plt2.set_ylabel("Bz",size=16)
plt2.get_yaxis().set_label_coords(-0.05,0.5)

plt3.plot("DOY", "Vsw", data=df,color='black')
plt3.set_ylabel("Vsw",size=16)
plt3.get_yaxis().set_label_coords(-0.05,0.5)

plt4.plot("DOY", "Nsw", data=df,color='black')
plt4.set_ylabel("Nsw",size=16)
plt4.get_yaxis().set_label_coords(-0.05,0.5)

plt5.plot("DOY", "reconnection_rate", data=df,color='black')
plt5.set_ylabel("MRR",size=16)
plt5.get_yaxis().set_label_coords(-0.05,0.5)

plt6.plot("DOY", "magnetopause_distance", data=df,color='black')
plt6.set_ylabel("MD",size=16)
plt6.set_xlabel("Day of Year",size=16)
plt6.get_yaxis().set_label_coords(-0.05,0.5)

#plt.subplots_adjust(hspace =  ,wspace = 5)
#saving plot in .jpg format
plt.savefig('3 to 6 July 2003 plot.jpg', format='jpeg',dpi=None, edgecolor='black', transparent=True, bbox_inches='tight')
```

UPDATE:
After trying `plt.margins(x=0)`
I am getting something like this
[image]

Comment: `from origin` ? From the left corner?

Comment: YEs from left corner. I want 0 and 184.0 to coincide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** For each of your `plt1`, `plt2`... (which are really axes), call `plt<i>.set_xlim(184)`.

---

In general it's good to give a running example, here is a short illustration derived from your code sample:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N = 100

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    DOY=np.linspace(184, 188, num=N),
    By=np.random.randn(N).cumsum(),
    Bz=np.random.randn(N).cumsum(),
))

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(611)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(612)

ax1.plot("DOY", "By", data=df, color="black")
ax2.plot("DOY", "Bz", data=df, color="black")

# This is the added part:
ax1.set_xlim(184)
ax2.set_xlim(184)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

I did not have your y-axis values, but I guess this answer will get you the main idea how to fix your problem.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = [184, 185, 186, 187, 188]

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(20,17))

plt1=fig.add_subplot(611)
plt1.plot(data=df,color='black')
plt1.set_ylabel("By",size=16)
plt1.set_title("3-6 July 2003",size=20)
plt1.get_yaxis().set_label_coords(-0.05,0.5)
plt1.set_xlim([df[0], df[-1]])
```